# Optimize Code causes Null Reference in Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton, nullreferenceexception

In my app, I have a static object which holds an instance of another object. I have a singleton which, in its constructor, calls the instance holder. The instance holder's instance is set before the `Singleton` is called, so this works fine. The problem arises when I turn on Optimize Code. Suddenly, I get a null reference to the instance holder's instance.

I'm using `Visual Studio 2017` with a `Console app` in `.NET 4.6.1` for this example. My main app is a `WPF` app and I'm calling the `Singleton` in the App() constructor.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
        var x = Singleton.Current;
    }
}

public static class StringHolder
{
    public static string ImportantString { get; set; }
}

public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Current { get; } = new Singleton();
    private Singleton()
    {
        var x = StringHolder.ImportantString.ToLower(); // Null Reference occurs here when Optimize Code is on.
    }
}
```

This seems to be caused by the `Singleton` being created *before* the first line in `Main` is called. Adding `Console.WriteLine()` calls shows this occurring.

One solution to this is splitting the `Main` function into to parts: setting the `ImportantString` and calling a `Part` function, which calls the `Singleton`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
    Part2();
}

public static void Part2()
{
    var x = Singleton.Current;
}
```

However, this solution does not work with the example code here: it only works in my main project. I'm not really sure why.

Another solution is to change the way `Singleton.Current` works:

```
public static Singleton _current;
public static Singleton Current => _current ?? (_current = new Singleton());
```

(This obviously fixes it since the static Property isn't being instantiated until it is called.)

A third solution is to add a static constructor:

```
static Singleton() { }
```

But, fixing my code isn't my concern. My concerns are as follows:

1. Why does turning Optimize Code on suddenly make the `Singleton` member be created early?
2. Why does the `Part2()` trick only work, but only in my main app?
3. Why does adding a static constructor fix the error?

Comment: The standard only guarantees that static constructors are called before the target object is used. However, you set `ImportantString` in your main function, which is outside the flow of static constructors; quite like a race condition (in this case though, no multi-threading is involved). This means that whether you get a NRE or not depends on the implementation. (Also, I believe that in most C implementations, static variables are initialized before `main` is called).

Answer (score 1):

Add some tracing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
        var x = Singleton.Current;
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}

public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Current { get; } = new Singleton();

    private Singleton()
    {
        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Calling ctor.");
            var x = StringHolder.ImportantString.ToLower(); // Null Reference occurs here when Optimize Code is on.
            Console.WriteLine("ctor called.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ctor failed with {e.GetType()}");
        }
    }
}

public static class StringHolder
{
    private static string importantString;

    public static string ImportantString
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting ImportantString");
            return importantString;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting ImportantString");
            importantString = value;
            Console.WriteLine("ImportantString set");
        }
    }
}
```

and run the program in `Debug` mode.

Output is:

```
Setting ImportantString
ImportantString set
Calling ctor.
Getting ImportantString
ctor called.
Done
```

Run the program in `Release` mode.

Output is:

```
Calling ctor.
Getting ImportantString
ctor failed with System.NullReferenceException
Setting ImportantString
ImportantString set
Done
```

`Debug` mode `IL` of `Main` is:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       30 (0x1e)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class OptimizationIssue.Singleton x)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Howdy"
  IL_0006:  call       void OptimizationIssue.StringHolder::set_ImportantString(string)
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  call       class OptimizationIssue.Singleton OptimizationIssue.Singleton::get_Current()
  IL_0011:  stloc.0
  IL_0012:  ldstr      "Done"
  IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001c:  nop
  IL_001d:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

`Release` mode `IL` of `Main` is:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "Howdy"
  IL_0005:  call       void OptimizationIssue.StringHolder::set_ImportantString(string)
  IL_000a:  call       class OptimizationIssue.Singleton OptimizationIssue.Singleton::get_Current()
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ldstr      "Done"
  IL_0015:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

`IL`s for both look pretty the same.

`Debug` mode `disassembly` of `Main` is:

```
        {
01A3084A  in          al,dx  
01A3084B  push        edi  
01A3084C  push        esi  
01A3084D  push        ebx  
01A3084E  sub         esp,38h  
01A30851  mov         esi,ecx  
01A30853  lea         edi,[ebp-44h]  
01A30856  mov         ecx,0Eh  
01A3085B  xor         eax,eax  
01A3085D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
01A3085F  mov         ecx,esi  
01A30861  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],ecx  
01A30864  cmp         dword ptr ds:[16042E8h],0  
01A3086B  je          01A30872  
01A3086D  call        7247F5A0  
01A30872  xor         edx,edx  
01A30874  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx  
01A30877  nop  
            StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
01A30878  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[4402334h]  
01A3087E  call        01A30458  
01A30883  nop  
            var x = Singleton.Current;
01A30884  call        01A30468  
01A30889  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
01A3088C  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  
01A3088F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax  
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
01A30892  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[4402338h]  
01A30898  call        70DD3CD4  
01A3089D  nop  
        }
01A3089E  nop  
01A3089F  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
01A308A2  pop         ebx  
01A308A3  pop         esi  
01A308A4  pop         edi  
01A308A5  pop         ebp  
01A308A6  ret
```

`Release` mode `disassembly` of `Main` is:

```
            StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
00D51072  in          al,dx  
00D51073  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3A32344h]  
00D51079  call        dword ptr ds:[0BF4DF4h]  
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
00D5107F  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3A32348h]  
00D51085  call        70DD3CD4  
00D5108A  pop         ebp  
00D5108B  ret
```

`disassembly`s differ much. `JIT-compilation` makes the difference. It appears `JIT-compilation` removes unused variable. But it still creates the type `OptimizationIssue.Singleton`, **calling its static constructor** before executing the `Main` method. Static constructor is created implicitly because of `public static Singleton Current { get; } = new Singleton();` in the code. When it's called `StringHolder.ImportantString` isn't set yet, it's null, so `NullReferenceException` is thrown when trying to call `ToLower()` on it.

Remove `var x = Singleton.Current;` from the `Main` and see `disassembly`:

```
            StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
00FE084A  in          al,dx  
00FE084B  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3BF2334h]  
00FE0851  call        dword ptr ds:[0CC4DF4h]  
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
00FE0857  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3BF2338h]  
00FE085D  call        70DD3CD4  
00FE0862  pop         ebp  
00FE0863  ret
```

It does not change much. We removed manually what compiler removed automatically. But `Singleton` type is no longer mentioned, so static constructor is not called, so there is no exception.

Addig `static Singleton() { }` changes `disassembly` to:

```
            StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
0169084A  in          al,dx  
0169084B  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[41F2334h]  
01690851  call        dword ptr ds:[1334DF4h]  
            var x = Singleton.Current;
01690857  call        dword ptr ds:[1334E60h]  
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
0169085D  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[41F2338h]  
01690863  call        70DD3CD4  
01690868  pop         ebp  
01690869  ret
```

Now it does not remove `var x = Singleton.Current;` for some reason and calls `Singleton` static constructor just befor executing the line, after `StringHolder.ImportantString` was set, so there is no exception.

[image]

It's **optimized** `JIT-compilation` magic. Don't rely on it. Remove `static Singleton() { }` from `Singleton` and better add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` to `Main`. (Or **much better** don't create objects you never use.)

Then output is:

```
Setting ImportantString
ImportantString set
Calling ctor.
Getting ImportantString
ctor called.
Done
```

`disassembly` is:

```
            StringHolder.ImportantString = "Howdy";
00DA084A  in          al,dx  
00DA084B  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3A42334h]  
00DA0851  call        dword ptr ds:[0B14DF4h]  
            var x = Singleton.Current;
00DA0857  call        dword ptr ds:[0B14E60h]  
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
00DA085D  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3A42338h]  
00DA0863  call        70DD3CD4  
00DA0868  pop         ebp  
00DA0869  ret
```

And everything works fine.

**The moral of the story**: `JIT-compilation` with **optimizations** is full of inlining, removing and many other things hard to foresee and able to change you code behavior in a weird way.